# Files aren't moved inside folders after that script extract year by file list (txt)

Tags: powershell

This scipt is for me an nightmare.

I try to extract year by file list and then move .torrent files in relative folders but unsuccessfully.

To create folder I try 2 powershell scripts

**create folders**

```
$movies = @()
(get-content C:\Path\Test4.txt) | foreach($_){
$properties = @{
date = $_.substring($_.IndexOf("(")+1,4)
name = $_.substring(0,$_.IndexOf("("))
}
$movies += New-Object PSObject -Property $properties
}
$movies
foreach($movie in $movies){
$movie.date
$datePath = "C:\Path\$($movie.date)"
if(-not(test-path $datePath)) {
new-item $datePath -ItemType "directory"
}
$words = $movie.name -split '\s'
$words
}
```

**create folders and try to match**

```
$movies = @()
(get-content C:\Path\Test4.txt) | foreach($_){
$properties = @{
date = $_.substring($_.IndexOf("(")+1,4)
name = $_.substring(0,$_.IndexOf("("))
}
write-host $date
write-host $name

$movies += New-Object PSObject -Property $properties
}

$torrentFiles = dir $torrentPath

foreach($movie in $movies){
$datePath = "C:\Path\$($movie.date)"
if(-not(test-path $datePath)) {
new-item $datePath -ItemType "directory"
}
$words = ($movie.name -split '\s') | ?{ $_.Length -gt 1}
$significant = $words.Count
 foreach($torrentFile in $torrentFiles){
 $matchingWords = 0
  foreach($word in $words){
   if($torrentFile.BaseName -match $word){
    $matchingWords += 1
   }
  }
  if($matchingWords -ge $significant){
  $_ | Move-Item -Destination $datePath
  }
 }
}
```

**Errors:**

```
System.ArgumentiException 
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null error
```

NB: 2nd script never stop !

I have expect this:

`film stackoverflow.torrent` ← file name torrent in *C:\Path*
`film stackoverflow (2006)` ← text string in file list in *C:\Path*

`film stackoverflow.torrent` **MOVE INTO FOLDER** `2006`

[image]

Comment: You should add some sample input lines and what you expect to be moved and to where.

Comment: **@notjustme** I add in answers what I expect: if in file list I have a file name torrent in string I want create a folder with year inside that string.
**@TessellatingHeckler** torrent files are in the same path of script. Script create folders but don't move torrent inside these folders ! I try to replace `foreach($torrentFile in $torrentFiles)` with `$torrentFile | Move-Item` but nothing happens

Comment: Script create folder correctly and now it move files but..in his way.. if I have text strings like `Charlie Zone (2011)` ,  `Charlie’s Angels (2000)`, `Charlie xcv (1999)` this script move every .torrent with `Charlie` in file name in the same year folder ! So in the same folder `1999` I find these three torrent. This causes disorder files instead order them per year.. Just what I did not want - Is there some fix ?